# Code igniter image folder outside app

Tags: codeigniter

I have 3 different CI projects and I would like to share the same image folder for all of them. Every CI project have the same structure:

  /var/www/project
  --------------------  application
  --------------------  css
  --------------------  system
  --------------------  ...

So long I have create a function to make it easier to link every image.

```
function img_source($uri = '')
{
    return 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/shared_img/'.$uri;
}
```

I have created a folder called shared_img under '/var/www/'. So my question now is, is it the correct and most secure way to do it? Do I have to give to the folder special privileges?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this way

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pilors/";
$path = $this->dire_path . "uploads/" . $up_folder . '/';
        $file_path_url = base_url() . 'uploads/' . $up_folder . '/' . $file_name;
        $file_path = $path . $file_name;

        if (move_uploaded_file($arr["tmp_name"], $file_path) > 0) {
            $ret = $file_path_url;
        } else {
            $ret = "";
        }
```

Comment: It's not for uploading images, just for share the same images on diferent webpages. To make and example I would like to share the same images for a slider that will be on 3 different webpages.